# What is a property that looks like it holds for all natural numbers but it turns out it doesn't?

Tags: induction, examples-counterexamples, natural-numbers

I want to find a simple example of a property that looks like it holds for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, but that does not. I remember reading about one that got in hold for centuries before someone found out a ridiculously big value of $n$ for which the property didn't hold, but I don't remember what the property was.

I'd like if the example property was easy to explain and didn't demand many concepts outside basic knowledge of the natural numbers.

Anything like that?

Comment: Well, a very basic one is that $n^2+n+41$ is prime, but you don't have to go far to disprove it.

Comment: Just read about this. For example purposes, n=40 is pretty big, so it works. thanks!

Comment: I believe you mean $n=41$.